# Access denied for mysql client with existing user even when apps are working properly

Tags: mysql, linux, mariadb

my apps are running properly with the database, but the MySQL client does not allow me to connect from a remote server.

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'myuser'@'application.domain' (using password: YES)
```

using and password

```
mysql -h XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX -u myuser -p
```

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user;
+-------+-------------------------+
| user  | host                    |
+-------+-------------------------+
| myuser| XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX         |
| myuser| hostname_of_appserver   |
| root  | localhost               |
+-------+-------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.000 sec)
```

Privileges were flushed. Everything works, but not the client.
secure setup was also used

What is wrong, please?

Comment: What happens if you run `mysql` with sudo?

Comment: I am under root, not set sudo yet, I am building system configs, so I use root until its finished, it is debian